# what's the better way to show key/value data

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, caching

My question background is like this:

A database table named *"User"*, "User" has a "State" column which value may be "0"(disabled),"1"(normal),"2"(other).

I need to show different text of "State" to different country user, that means "disabled" or "禁用"(chinese char) should be showed rather than "0".

Now, I design a "mapping" table named *"Code"* with columns :"Code","Value","Locale(Country)","Type". Should I join the two table("User" and "Code") to show the locale dependable value, or using another query to get it(I think query cache could be used).

Note: "Type" column in "Code" table is for category the code. for example: "User" has a "State", "Menu" has a "State".

What's your choice? and reason. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that your table with Code, Value, Locale and Type is a lookup table for State?  If it is, then that sounds fine.  However, as you haven't mentioned what these columns mean it's difficult to say whether that is the right approach.

Also, it depends a lot on how you are accessing the data.

If you are trying to get the full output in a SQL query then the way in which I would do it would be to have a lookup table specifically for State with only two columns, State and StateDescription.  Join to that lookup table on State and pull back the StateDescription to display to the user.

If you are displaying the data in SSRS or similar then it may be a good move to hard code the Descriptions in there based on the value of State.  This would avoid the cost of a join from the query.

Comment: en... I am not sure what SSRS data like, but my situation is like this: 

column name:state; 
possible values are:0,1,2; 
responsible text including english and chinese:
eg:'saved','submited','canceled' and chinese text like '已保存','已提交','已取消';

I need to show difference kind of text to different locale user. And sometime i need to get all value under the same code type. So, property i18n files may not be so convinient than database.

Answer (score 0):

If the "State" not always changes, I will use [ENUM column](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/enum.html) .

Answer (score 0):

guys, I have found the right way! property files.
First, why not use database? Because 'state' is not a dictionary column, it's a biz column which has limited biz-related values. So, developers rather than system administor should be responsible to maintain them. 
Property files are one of the proper way for developers to do it.